# How to create horizontal menu in fixed sized div with one link wider than the others

Tags: html, css

So my problem is this - I have a div with fixed size of 970px. Inside it I want to create a horizontal menu where the first element will be a link to the home page with the logo of the company and the others will be standard links to different parts of the page.

What I want is to make the link with the logo wider than the other links and let the other links occupy the space left equally. Due to the fact that in near future the width of the container div may be changed even though I know the number of links I would like to use percentages to determine their width so the width of one link will be = (width of the div - width of the logo link)/5 (the number of link I'll have.

I tried with something like this

```
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="logo-container">
  </div>

  <div id="standard-menu-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

But I couldn't make it work (In fact all this is wrapped in one other div that I haven't shown here). So googling about this I get to the understanding that maybe using some sort of table may solve my problem. To be honest I have never used table this way but I followed an example and I got this result : [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LREbC/) where the red rectangle is meant to be my Logo link and the problem is that everything else is stacking under. In this particular example the logo link is excluded from the `<ul>` but I played around with that case too and simply trying to set one width in pixels and other - in percentage seems to be not what I need to do.

I would appreciate any help, just bare in mind that I tried a lot of styling with divs and `display: inline-block` and it breaks other parts of my structure so I would prefer a solution where the normal flow is not disturbed (like using a table for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right lines with the `display: table-cell`.  I've made a few changes where you had extra code that wasn't needed, and set the `<ul>` to `display: table`, rather than the container.  Adding `table-layout: fixed` will make items in the list (the cells) occupy an equal width.

Then, float the logo left, don't specify a width for #main-menu-navigation because then it will fill remaining space, and give it `margin-left: 150px` to cater for width of logo.

So that won't make much sense when read.  Take a look here:

**http://jsfiddle.net/LREbC/1/**

Try resizing, the cells will adapt to the width.

Note: When using `table-cell` you don't need to define a width, the behaviour is the same as actual table cells.

Comment: I tried this for my real example and it's not working entirely as I want. Maybe it's just something in my code here, but looking at the example you use the whole width of the page where I want my menu + the logo to take only part of the page. Could this be causing any troubles?

Comment: You can set a width on `#main-menu`, it will adjust automatically.  http://jsfiddle.net/LREbC/2/

Comment: Sorry, just sleepy. I've played around and it's perfect. Thanks for the support. Cheers! :)

Comment: Haha sleepy coding.  Glad to help